# Prove that $a_1.a_2......a_p<=((a_1+a_2+.........+a_p)/p)^p$, where $p=2^m$, using mathematical induction on m.

Tags: induction

The quantities $a_i$ are all positive real numbers.

(a) Show that

$$a_1.a_2 \leq \left(\frac{a_1 + a_2}{2}\right)^2$$

(b) Hence prove, by induction on m, that

$$a_1.a_2.......a_p \leq \left(\frac{a_1+a_2+......+a_p}{p}\right)^p$$ ,

where $p = 2^m$ with m a positive integer. Note that each increase of m by unity doubles the number of factors in the product.

The (a) part of the problem can be proved by using the expansion of $(a_1+a_2)^2$,
for the (b) part: taking $m=1$ gives $p = 2$ (base case), which is same as the (a) part.

Assuming that: $$a_1.a_2.....a_P \leq \left(\frac{a_1+a_2+.......+a_P}{P}\right)^P$$ (taking $m=M$ so that $p = P = 2^M$);

Substituting $m = M+1 \Rightarrow p = 2P = 2^{M+1}$ on the L.H.S. : 
$$a_1.a_2....a_P.a_{P+1}.a_{P+2}.....a_{2P} \Rightarrow$$
$$\left(\frac{a_1+a_2+.....+a_P}{P}\right)^P.a_{P+1}.a_{P+2}.....a_{2P}$$
How to proceed from here on?

Comment: Do you try to prove the $$AM-GM$$ inequality?

Comment: See the proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means